# UIImageView aspect ratio issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am currently placing a .png image to a UIImageView whose resolution for this purpose is 1024 × 1136. This causes the UIImageView to have a black border at both top and bottom.[image] how can this be corrected.

---

Comment: the contentMode for the UIImageView is AspectFill

Comment: Where is the code you are using to position the UIImageView? if you are using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, the image should be filling the whole visible bounds of the UIImageView. What is likely happening is that the actual size of the UIImageView is too small. Show us how you are creating it and setting its frame.

Comment: The UIImageView was placed through InterfaceBuilder and the image is also placed through interface builder. no code.

Comment: was the image view placed to take up the entire size of its superview? and does that superview extend to the vertical edges of the screen (enclosing the black bars)?

Comment: yes the superview encloses the blackbar. Its the view of the ViewController.

Comment: and is the imageview positioned to take up the entire view?

Comment: make sure you test your solution on both 3.5" and 4" screen! you are OK with the image being stretched as necessary to fill the space?

Comment: Thanks guys it just a random bug... i cleaned the entire project and it started working. Thanks a lot for your responses.